# ActiveModel::Serializer define attribute attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to implement the JSON API for my Rails app. It requires [attributes](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-attributes) field to be defined. But `ActiveModel::Serializer` has a method with the same name, hence

```
class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :attributes

  def attributes
    {
      # to be filled
    }
  end
end
```

will just override the original method. Is that ever possible to add the **attributes** field somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveModel Serializer has support for JSON API out of the box. You just need to setup the proper adapter.

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/adapters.md

Comment: It produces a JSON object, but doesn't create an attributes container.

Comment: which version of AMS are you using. also can you show the AMS initialiser file

Comment: I use AMS v 0.9.3

config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb

```ruby
ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
    config.adapter = :json_api
end
```

Comment: ahh ok, i think **json_api** support is only in 0.10. I would suggest to use that (it's in RC already) otherwise you can use, one of the other libraries listed in [JSON API page](http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-ruby). IMO, monkypatching AMS will be more painful :)

Answer (score 1):

here's how to do it:

```
class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def attributes(*args)
    hash = super
    hash[:attributes] = attributes_list
    hash
  end

  def attributes_list
    {
      # to be filled
    }
  end
end
```